# Why is this field not being updated in the SQLLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I know I'm missing something simple. I made a website manager that uses `SQLite` to keep track of ftp address, login details, home directory, url, etc. I have an `Activity` that lets the user select and edit a site's details When an Update button is clicked it updates the site's row in the database however the only database value I can't save is the `_remoteHomeDir` var for the website's remote directory. Why isn't this value updating?

```
siteManUpdateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        _address = siteManFTPAddress.getText().toString();
        _username = siteManFTPUsername.getText().toString();
        _password = siteManFTPPassword.getText().toString();
        String port = siteManFTPPort.getText().toString();
        _port = Integer.parseInt(port);
        _url = siteManHome.getText().toString();
        _remoteHomeDir = siteManHome.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(SiteManager.this, "Update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    myDb.updateRow(_rowId, _name,  _name, _isLive, _address, _username, _password, _port, _url,_remoteHomeDir);
    model.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    displayRecords();
    }
});
```

DBAdapter.java

```
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, String homedir,
    int islive, String address, String username, String password,
    int port, String url, String rhome) {
String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

/*
 * CHANGE 4:
 */
// TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
// TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
// Create row's data:
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + name);
newValues.put(KEY_HOME, homedir);
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + homedir);
newValues.put(KEY_LIVE, islive);
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + islive);
newValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + address);
newValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + username);
newValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + password);
newValues.put(KEY_PORT, port);
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + port);
newValues.put(KEY_URL, url);
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + url);
newValues.put(KEY_RHOME, rhome);
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + rhome);
// newValues.put(KEY_PASSIVE, passive);
// Insert it into the database.
Log.d("tag", "there is something happening here: " + db.toString());
return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}
```

Comment: check out your row-id value, is it valid or not

Comment: it has to be if it works for every field but one doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are reading same values for both _url and _remoteHomeDir from the edittext siteManHome.  This can be a mistake and may be you have separate edit texts in the GUi

That is:

```
_url = siteManHome.getText().toString();
_remoteHomeDir = siteManHome.getText().toString();
```

Maybe you meant to get `_remoteHomeDir` from a different field?

Comment: Thanks @janos for editing my answer.  I answered from Mobile phone so no option to format (and not to mention how hard it would if there was option).